# Closing Navigation Tab On Click away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

Hi i have the following code to create a navigation tab and it closes when i click on one of the lists on there but not if i click away, i am new to this so any help would be great

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, iniitial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION TAB-->

<nav>

    <a href="#" class="nav-togg"></a>

    <ul>
    <h1 class="navhead1">HOME</h1>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


</nav>

<script       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


(function() {

    var bodyEl = $('body'),
        navTogg = bodyEl.find('.nav-togg');

        navTogg.on('click', function(e){
            bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
            e.preventDefault();

        });



})();
```

I want to get it to close when i click away anywhere on the page
thanks

Shaq

Answer (score 0):

This can handle by check clicked area:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
 if($(e.target).closest('.nav-togg').length)
     $('body').toggleClass('active-nav');
 else
     $('body').removeClass('active-nav');
    });
});
```

```css
nav ul{
  display: none; 
}
.active-nav nav ul{
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>

    <a href="#" class="nav-togg">toggle</a>

    <ul>
    <h1 class="navhead1">HOME</h1>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


</nav>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, am not very familiar with this all so what do i need to add and to where? thanks shaq –